# Can I store a CWM backup on the PC and copy it to the phone when needed?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery

I was wondering if I could just simply copy the backup file and when needed copy back to the phone....because it takes up almost 3 G space. Weird that it is that big.

By the way....I cant even locate the backupfile. Where is the default folder for it?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I store a CWM backup on the PC and copy it to the phone when
>   needed?

**Yes, you can.**

> `CWM` backups are stored in `/data/media/clockworkmod/backups`

**And for TWRP :**

> you can choose the *files/backup-files* for saved and stored in Sdcard or Extsdcard
>   during backup process.

```
Stored in -> sdcard -> TWRP -> Backups
```

**or:**       `Extsdcard -> TWRP -> Backups`

and then, you can copy this backup when needed into the phone and then,
Restore it from related recovery.

Comment: hey LinX64. I cant find /data/media/clockworkmod/backups when I connect the phone to my PC (I use linux mint). There is actually no trace of CWM and the back up was successful and the space is occupied by it when I check the storage on the phone.

Comment: and how about in : `sdcard/extsdcard -> Clockworkmod -> backup` ? still not exist? update the recovery or change it with `twrp`.maybe it fixed in next or latest version.But, `twrp` worked fine.

Comment: the thing is that it doesnt have an SD card....it is a Moto G with only external memory. I am kinda new to it and I am not sure I wanna learn how to use twrp. I'd like to leave the phone as it is now...dont wanna mess with it anymore.

Comment: I have also just installed CWM backup manager and it says there are no backup on my phone. This simply doesnt make any sense. I made a sucessfull backup with CWM last night and it also occupies the space of its size.

Comment: @Elysium learning TWRP? There isn't such thing. It is very easy anyway. If you wanna stick to CWM though, `/data` partion is somewhere a non-root user can not reach. You'll need to root your phone and install a file explorer like ES or FX.

Answer (score -1):

I used to have the same question as you mentioned: (`/data/media/clockworkmod/backups` cannot be found), now here is how I solved it.

In addition to [LinX64's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/107264/119358), in order to access that folder, it requires **root** privilege.

After rooted, with the help of File explorer, I copied the files to *download* folder, then pull them out to PC.

Answer (score -1):

Check `/mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod/backup`.